# Perl: Colouring Term::Readline messages while keeping underline ornament (and potentially others)

Tags: perl, readline

I want to use `Term::Readline` with colourful prompts, something along the lines of: `readline("foo" . colored("bar", "red") . "baz")`

I found  `Term::ANSIColor` and it looks promising. It does, however, seem to clear all colours or underlining after, i.e.  `colored("some text", "red")`.

That is bad because 
 the prompt generated by `readline` contains underlining. Sometimes, that is.

I guess `colored` doesn't know what formatting has been applied before and I wasn't able to find out whether [Colorstacks, mentioned in the documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Term/ANSIColor.html#The-Color-Stack), will help me. The documentation has only examples which directly `print` stuff and is -at best- is not well suited for Perl newbies like me.

The problem is that the prompt generated by `readline` doesn't look consistent, because it is underlined first and after the coloured part, the underlining is gone:

[image: perl and colours]

I can read the "ornaments" which seem to be relevant for the underlining to happen, as seen in the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Term::ReadLine;
use Term::ANSIColor;

my $term;

sub prompt {
    $term = new Term::ReadLine 'colourtest'
        unless $term;
    print "My ornaments: " . $term->ornaments . "\n";
    my $answer = $term->readline(@_);
    # readline turns off autoflush, re-enable it
    $| = 1;
    return $answer;
}
prompt("Underlined " . 
    colored("followed by colour", "red") . 
    " then plain");
```

I guess my question is: Can I make  `Term::ANSIColor` play well together with `readline`  such that `colored` falls back to the previously applied formatting?

Comment: Anyway, I think the problem is that `colored()` makes a full reset, not changing only colors but also other attributes, and you cannot do anything about it. Maybe best is too fully take over control of the prompt coloring. Just do a `color 'reset'` at the beginning of the prompt.